# Loop must iterate over collection: Contact

Tags: apex, contact, for

I'm trying to executing this logic in my console. But getting an error. Please correct me

```
    List<Contact> conList = new List<Contact>(FirstName='Test', LastName = 'T', ZTS_EU_Contact_Status__c = 'Active', ZTS_EU_District__c = 'Testdistrict',ZTS_EU_Species_Specialty__c = 'Cats',ZTS_EU_Contact_type__c = 'Other', AccountId = '001F000001IgAtZIAV');

for(Contact con:conList){
    
    if(con.Account.ZTS_EU_Market__c != null){
        
        con.ZTS_EU_Market__c = con.Account.ZTS_EU_Market__c;
        System.debug('Market:::'+con.ZTS_EU_Market__c);
        
    }else{
        
        Id userId = UserInfo.getUserId();
        String userMarket = [Select ZTS_EU_Market__c from User where Id = :userId][0].ZTS_EU_Market__c;
        con.ZTS_EU_Market__c = userMarket;  
        System.debug('Market--->>>'+con.ZTS_EU_Market__c);          
    }   
}
```

### Error:

Line: 1, Column: 6
Unexpected token '<'.

If any ideas it would be great help

Thanks,
Venkata

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange. Look very carefully at your first line.  Just because you name your variable `conList` does not make it a List.  `conList` needs to be of type `List<Contact>` (a List is a type of collection) for you to iterate/loop over it.  You need to create a `Contact` and put it in a `List<Contact>`.

Comment: @Moonpie updated the code still getting an error. Kindly please check provide some inputs. Thanks

Comment: I was not trying to get you to just change your original code to make `conList` a LIst of Contacts. With my last sentence in my previous comment I was trying to help guide you into the direction of thinking through it - rather than just giving you an answer.  Trying to teach you to fish instead of giving you a fish (https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/teach+a+man+to+fish).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the field parameters to the List constructor instead of the Contact's record constructor. Also the list literal syntax is wrong, you need to use curly braces instead of parenthesis.

```
List<Contact> conList = new List<Contact>{
    new Contact(
        FirstName = 'Test',
        LastName = 'T',
        ZTS_EU_Contact_Status__c = 'Active',
        ZTS_EU_District__c = 'Testdistrict',
        ZTS_EU_Species_Specialty__c = 'Cats',
        ZTS_EU_Contact_type__c = 'Other',
        AccountId = '001F000001IgAtZIAV'
    )
};
```